# How to set the path for one cron command

Tags: cron, path

I had programmed a cronjob to restart a service with an apparent memory leak weekly and got an email saying that the `killproc` command wasn't found.

That's in /sbin/killproc and I don't want to modify the service script, even though I'd prefer it to use absolute paths so I'm opting to weasel my fix by way of cron.

So, I don't want to set the `PATH` at the top of the crontab file as per the man page apparently says (according to other posts I've seen on the internet, not my man page).  How can I structure my crontab line to set one path variable (and not squash root's PATH altogether) just for this script?

**tl;dr;**

This is what I want to do

```
0 0 * * 0 /etc/init.d/tic_minus restart
```

this is what I want to avoid

> To: Stupid
>
> From: All your customers
>
> Stopping tic_minus: /etc/init.d/tic_minus: line 43: killproc: command not found
>
> Starting tic_minus:

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use a sub-shell to limit scope:

```
0 0 * * 0 (export PATH=$PATH:/sbin; /etc/init.d/tic_minus restart)
```

Comment: or, more simply: `... PATH=$PATH:/sbin /etc/init.d/tic_minus restart`

Comment: @Jeff I think that might be better since I just got `line 48: sleep: command not found` by trying this...

Comment: Just updated mine to append to the existing PATH.

Comment: cron already starts a subshell for your command, so there's not a real need to start a second one; try and see!

Comment: @JeffSchaller Good point!

Comment: I accepted this, although I did not use the parentheses.  It seems to me that it's not entirely useless to convey to future maintainers that the script is intended to be be ran in a subshell.

Answer (score 1):

Never trust cron env -version => source env setup before command.

```
0 0 * * 0   (. /usr/xx/myenv ; /some/cmd ) >> /usr/xx/mylog.log 2>&1
```

myenv include all setup what you need. PATH etc. Use export for variables.